# jQuery slider onclick event loop photos

Tags: jquery

I am creating a very simple slideshow based onclick event using jQuery. When the user clicks on the next button, the slider would margin-left: -=400px. The slider is working great but when it gets to the last slider and the user clicks again the button it wont show anything, it will just go -=400px. What i would like to happen is, when the user clicks when he is on the last img, to show the first image then second and so on. I would like to have endless loop when someone is clicking the button. Hopefully someone can help with this issue.

Thanks.

HTML code:

```
<div class="slideClick">
        <ul class="sliderClick">
            <li class="slidesClick"><img src ="imgs/model_01.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slidesClick"><img src ="imgs/model_02.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slidesClick"><img src ="imgs/model_03.jpeg"></li>
            <li class="slidesClick"><img src ="imgs/model_04.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slidesClick"><img src ="imgs/model_01.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
</div>
    <button class="clickPrev">Prev</button>
    <button class="clickNext">Next</button>
```

CSS code:

```
.slideClick {
    clear: both;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.slideClick .sliderClick{
    width:2000px;
    height:400px;
}

.slideClick .sliderClick .slidesClick {
    list-style: none;
}

.slideClick .sliderClick .slidesClick img{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
var currentClickSlider = 1;

$(".clickNext").on("click", function(){
   $(".sliderClick").animate({marginLeft: "-=400px"}, 500, function(){

       currentClickSlider++;
       if ( currentClickSlider === $(".slidesClick").length ){

           currentClickSlider = 1;
           $(".sliderCLick").css("margin-left", 0);
       }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (currentClickSlider === $(".slidesClick").length + 1) {
```

What you want to do is check if the element is the last element. The counter starts at 1, so after N + 1 elements we repeat the slider.

Comment: Thank u Warrior for ur answer. However it was my mistake that i have not included the .length at the end. I have used ur code but it is still not working.

Comment: There are a few mistypes, for example $(".sliderCLick") into the animate callback function. I advise to place the code which restarts the slider out of the callback, because you want to reset it's state before doing any animation. First you check which element you're trying to display and then animate based on that.

Comment: If u r not busy can u show me how would u would write the code please? in order for this to work?